# Last line of NSAttributedString not rendered in UILabel

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have text which contains HTML formatting that I am trying to render on a view.  Currently I am using an `NSAtributedString` to display the text inside a `UILabel`.

I obtain the attributed string as follows:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html>"
    "  <head>"
    "    <style type='text/css'>"
    "      body { font: 12pt 'Helvetica'; color: #111111; }"
    "    </style>"
    "  </head>"
    "  <body>";
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:self.descriptionText];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                          options: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                               documentAttributes: nil
                                                                            error: &err];
```

and then assign it to my label's `attributedText` property.  The property self.descriptionText is an `NSString` which can contain simple HTML markup such as `p` tags or `span` tags with inline styles. The technique of wrapping the string in an HTML document was found on another StackOverflow post.

The `UILabel` is set to Lines = 0 and Line Breaks = Word Wrap.  The behavior that I am seeing is that the label grows properly to accommodate the whole string, but the last line of the string is never rendered, no matter how long the string is.

Here is a screen capture with two labels.  The top label (with a yellow background) has my HTML attributed string in it.  You can see that the label has sized itself to allow 3 rows of text, but only two are rendered and the rest is truncated.  The second label (with a red background) has had a plain string assigned to its Text property and it draws just fine.

The HTML string used in the example image contains the following text:

```
<p>With the world&#39;s longest fan-vaulted ceiling, an original Reubens painting, and an excellent collection of medieval stained glass, this chapel has intrigue from multiple angles</p>
```

[image: screen capture with two labels. The top has an NSAttributedString, the bottom has a plain NSString.]

An acceptable answer would explain how I can prevent the last line from being truncated or provide a simple alternative method for rendering HTML text to a view.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the String `htmlString` just plain text or html markup? If so, please show us the string.

Comment: the htmlString does contain simple HTML markup.  I added more code for clarity.

Comment: I think issue is with label height. Try to set height of the label ore than it is currently.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora I am using auto-layout and I would prefer not to get into the business of manually laying out the elements in my view. Auto-layout seems to be attempting to work, given the fact that the label is larger at runtime than its size in the IB. I did attempt to increase the size of the height of the label in code, but it had no visible effect. I assume auto-layout was undoing my changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  It is not an obvious solution, but I did do a face-palm after discovering it.

The problem is that the `p` tag is being given a margin and/or padding, which is pushing the text outside of the bounds of the `UILabel`.  I don't know why it isn't being taken into consideration when the size of the string is computed, but I don't care anymore.

The solution was for me to add `p {margin:0; padding:0;}` to the style tag that I was prepending to the HTML string. Now all of the string is drawn properly inside the UILabel.

Comment: I had the same problem, but removing paragraph spacing really didn't look very good. Instead, I added a "<br/>" to the end, and that worked too!

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this as well. Apparently UILabel has some difficulties calculating the correct size when showing an `attributedText` that has the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` attribute set.

I solved my problem by removing this attribute from my `NSMutableAttributedString` before assigning it to my label like so:

```
[mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedString.length)];
```

The effect is the same, but it feels a bit tidier than prepending some inline css.

Comment: This solution appears to work for me too. I suppose the desired solution depends on whether you care about styling <p> tags or not.

Comment: I didn't dig into it very far, but if you want to apply a specific style to <p> tags, I think you can do it through the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` too. This way you could easily make sure that styles are applied consistently throughout your app. The downside of course is that depending on the styling you apply, you're likely to end up with truncated lines again.

Comment: If you want to keep the attribute, trying adding minimumLineHeight to the NSParagraphStyle. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the new iOS 11.

My solution was, to insert a css line-height. Although it doesn't affect the displayed line height, it solved the issue and now all lines are displayed

`body {font-size:14px;line-height:14px;}p {margin:0;padding:0;line-height:14px;}`